# In R: How to create a column such that there is an initial value, and each next value is previous plus a set integer

Tags: r, list, reference

I apologize if this is a repetitive question to others listed... I have looked and looked and tried multiple ideas but can't seem to find a working answer.

I have a column "Expected" within list TFAOS with multiple columns.

edit: dataframe is: 
patients <- c(1:17)
 
Expected <- c(0) 
TFAOS <- data.frame(patients, Expected)

Expected should be:

Expected 
17/24 
previous value + 17/24 
previous value + 17/24 
etc. for 17 rows

OR THE EQUIVALENT:

Expected 
17/24 * 1 
17/24 * 2 
17/24 * 3 
etc. for 17 rows

Can anyone help with a simple solution?

I have tried:
TFAOS[1,2]=17/24 
TFAOS[2:17, 2] = TFAOS$Expected[-1] + 17/24

AND

mutate(TFAOS, Expected = 17/24 + lag(Expected, default =0))

These both just give the same 17/24 value for each row.

Thank you so so much in advance.

Comment: It’s easier to help if you provide the data in a format that people can copy and paste into R as a data set.   Also what is 17/24 here?  Is it supposed to be character (text) or is it supposed to be numerical?

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I will post in a repeatable format below. 17/24 is a numerical value (0.7083333).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another way you could do using your data:

```
# package load
library(tidyverse)

# data
patients <- c(1:17) 
Expected <- c(0) 
TFAOS <- data.frame(patients, Expected)

# constant to add
myconstant <- 17/24


# mutate
TFAOS <- TFAOS %>%
    mutate(Expected = Expected + (patients - 1) * myconstant)

print(TFAOS)
```

Comment: Works perfectly as well! like using mutate as it can be done in one step and more transferable. thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can try `mutate(Expected = 1:n()*17/4 )`

Answer (score 1):

Not totally sure I'm answering your question, but this code will take an initial value, a vector length, and a step size and give you a vector which starts at the initial value, and increases by the step size (possibly an integer) in each successive element.

```
out_length <- 10 # length of the vector you want
increment <- 4 # amount to increment in each step
initial <- 3 # starting value
(0:(out_length - 1))*increment + initial # the desired vector
[1]  3  7 11 15 19 23 27 31 35 39
```

Comment: Thank you very much! this works perfectly on a fundamental level